# Error : object is not JSON serializable Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem passing an object using pusher it gives me an error `Error: new_action is not JSON serializable`. I tried `json.dumps(new_action)` but still not working. Here is my code :

**views.py:**

```
 new_action = Action(actor=actor, verb=verb, action_object=action_object,description=description, target=target)
 new_action.save()
 p['stream_' + str(actor.username)].trigger('liveStream', {
        'new_action': new_action,
 });
 return new_action
```

Comment: Add a link to this `pusher` module. Also what is `p`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your attached code but try this:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

# ...

json.dumps(new_action, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

I hope that helps.